# Looking for enterprise solution for breaking text into sentences

Tags: php, nlp, linguistics

It's easy to develop manual/regex-based algorithm for splitting text into sentences. But ignoring semantics will eventually lead to parse errors while processing big amounts of text.

I am looking for enterprise level solution, which analyzes semantics as well and provides accurate results.

Targeted language is EN.

Comment: Google > natural language processing. Check if anything fits your needs.

Comment: Nltk in python provides good reliable resultat as long as the right functions are used. But from your question I assume you didn't considered that one.

Comment: @Einar Please, convert your comment into an answer. Just because it is one.

Answer (score 3):

I did some analysis on the accuracy of different sentence segmentation tools which you can find in the [README of my sentence segmentation Ruby gem](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter) or on this [page](https://www.tm-town.com/natural-language-processing). The programming language of each tool is also noted for most. I haven't come across any segmentation tools written natively in PHP. My guess is that if you want an enterprise solution you will need to port a tool from another programming language (or find someone who already has).

Sentence segmentation tools:

- [Standford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)
- [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)
- [TactfulTokenizer](https://github.com/zencephalon/Tactful_Tokenizer)
- [Pragmatic Segmenter](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter)
- [Splitta](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html)
- [Punkt](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html)
- [SRX English](https://github.com/apohllo/srx-english)
- [Scapel](https://github.com/louismullie/scalpel)
- [FreeLing](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/)
- [Alpino](http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/alp/Alpino/)
- [trtok](https://github.com/jirkamarsik/trainable-tokenizer)
- [segtok](https://github.com/fnl/segtok)
- [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentences/read-me.html)
- [Elephant](http://gmb.let.rug.nl/elephant/experiments.php)
- [Ucto: Unicode Tokenizer](http://ilk.uvt.nl/ucto/)
- [tokenizer](http://moin.delph-in.net/WeSearch/DocumentParsing)
- [spaCy](http://honnibal.github.io/spaCy/)

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive list. Language is not nearly a problem as text being analyzed statically and sentences then written to database.

Answer (score 1):

[Nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) in python provides good reliable result as long as the right functions are used. 
Also [Apaches open NLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) should be considered.